# How should I format a USB prior to writing an ISO to it?

Tags: filesystems, usb, dd

I found [these Debian EeePC HowToInstallUsingStandardInstaller](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianEeePC/HowTo/InstallUsingStandardInstaller) instructions at the Debian Wiki, stating that I can install an ISO to a USB using this:

```
dd if=debian-*-netinst.iso of=/dev/sdX
```

- Do I need to delete the contents of the USB prior to running this so that nothing is left at the end of the USB?
- Does it matter what filesystem is already present on the USB prior to running this command?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Writing to the device (`/dev/sdX`) instead of to a file system (`/mount/point`) deletes the file system on the device anyway so there's no need for `mkfs` before.

There is also no need to erase data in the non-written area. It is not visible anyway. Linux file systems can without problems be smaller than the block device they live on.

Answer (score 7):

The `dd` command overwrites everything on the USB device. No preparation is required.

Answer (score 4):

You don't *need* to erase the old data first. But you can if you *want* to. 
Sometimes it's a good idea. Particularly if you're giving it to someone.

This should do the trick:

**Linux:**

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx
```

**Macintosh:**

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/diskx
```

```
diskutil zeroDisk /dev/diskx
```

Where `sdx` or `diskx` is the target disk. Usually, `sda`/`disk0` is the first disk, containing the main OS, etc. (*i.e. SCSI/SATA Disk A*), followed by `sdb`/`disk1`, `sdc`/`disk2`, and so on.
If you have one internal disk (`/dev/sda` or `/dev/disk0`), and you connect an external drive via USB; the external drive will be `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/disk1`. You get the idea. SD cards are designated names like `/dev/mmcblk0` and so on, in a similar fashion.

Some refer to this as *zeroing* or *low-level formatting*. The pseudo-file [`/dev/zero`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%2Fdev%2Fzero) can be thought of as being similar to [`/dev/null`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%2Fdev%2Fnull); but designed to be *read from*, rather than *written to*. It will supply a steady stream of ASCII [`NUL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) (`0x00`) bytes to whatever process tries to read from it.

The original filesystem will be overwritten.

---

Some additional options that people commonly like to use with [`dd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix_software%29), to manipulate block size & data read/write speeds follow the syntax:

```
bs=512kB count=1
```

Also, I personally like to have a running status/progress report so I can tell what's going on; to do this, just add the following to the tail end of the command:

```
status=progress
```

---

Take care to specify the correct disk. Especially if copying/pasting commands like this directly into a shell. It takes milliseconds to bork the wrong partition table. To list your storage devices, begin with:

**Linux:**

```
lsblk
```

**Macintosh:**

```
diskutil list
```

The output will look something like this:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            499.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```